# Postgresql - update a row based upon last highest value from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with columns:

```
id (PK),
low_value,
high_value
```

Id and high_value is populated in this table and low_value needs to be populated using populated data.
Low_value should be the previous ordered high_value in the table.

Example - table data before updating low_value:

```
id     | low_value      | high_value
---------------------------------------
1      |                | 1000
2      |                | 1000  
3      |                | 2000  
4      |                | 5000  
5      |                | 7000  
6      |                | 10000 
7      |                | 10000 
8      |                | 20000
```

table data after updating low_value should be:

```
id     | low_value      | high_value
---------------------------------------
1      |    0           | 1000
2      |    0           | 1000  
3      |    1000        | 2000  
4      |    2000        | 5000  
5      |    5000        | 7000  
6      |    7000        | 10000 
7      |    7000        | 10000 
8      |    10000       | 20000
```

I am thinking of assigning a rank (using window function rank()) to each row based upon high_value,
so rows with same high_value will have same rank and then pick the value with rank less than current rank for the row getting updated.
But i am not able to construct the sql. Can anyone help with the sql with or without ranking rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have duplicate `high_value`s in consecutive `id`s `LAG()` will not always return the correct value.
For each row you must get the `high_value` of the row with the max id `with` a different `high_value` than the current row:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY id) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
           LAG(high_value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) prev_high_value,
           (high_value <> LAG(high_value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id))::int flag
    FROM tablename
  ) t  
)
UPDATE tablename t
SET low_value = new_value
FROM (
  SELECT *, FIRST_VALUE(prev_high_value) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY flag DESC) new_value
  FROM cte
) c
WHERE t.id = c.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c6ddba3e241aa09944fb5b2c4a2692ae).

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . it is a little strange that there are duplicates.  Assuming the values are ordered, you can use:

```
update t
    set low_value = coalesce(prev_high_value, 0)
    from (select high_value,
                 lag(high_value) over (order by high_value) as prev_high_value
          from t
          group by high_value
         ) tt
    where tt.high_value = t.high_value
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, but this is not working, for first 10000 it has prev_high_value = 7000 but for next 7000 it is 7000 itself.

Comment: @user10916892 . . . As written, there was a typo and it should not have run.  However, is it possible that you are storing the value as a string and not as a number?  If so, you should fix the *data*.  Do not store numbers as strings!